# Using sed with two possible input formats

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I want to parse the repository from github, which comes in two formats:

for ssh:

`Fetch URL: git@github.com:the/partIWant.git`

for https:

`Fetch URL: https://github.com/the/partIWant.git`

The command I use for ssh is:

`echo "Fetch URL: git@github.com:the/partIWant.git" | sed 's/.*://;s/.git$//'`

and for https:

`echo "Fetch URL: https://github.com/the/partIWant.git" | sed 's/.*https:\/\/github.com//;s/.git$//'`

How can I combine both, in order to parse correctly, regardless of the type?

Comment: The output of both commands is subtly different: The first is `/the/partIWant` and the second is `the/partIWant` - can you clarify what output you are expecting? Presumably it should be identical?

Comment: you are right, I would like to get `the/partIWant`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only care about repository from `github.com`? You can use the pattern to do

```
sed 's/.*github\.com.//;s/.git$//'
```

See the output

```
$ echo "Fetch URL: https://github.com/the/partIWant.git" | sed 's/.*github\.com.//;s/.git$//'
the/partIWant
$ echo "Fetch URL: git@github.com:the/partIWant.git" | sed 's/.*github\.com.//;s/.git$//'
the/partIWant
```